# Laravel putFile method error file does not exist but putFileAs works fine

Tags: laravel, filenotfoundexception, file-not-found

I want to download and store some icon image files. first of all I tried using Storage::putFileAs method. It downloads the file normally but there is a problem with this method as it doesn't add the file extension to file name and I don't know how can I get the file extension before using this method. But I tried using putFile to see if it will guess file extension but it gives me error below **on same url**.

`Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/Exception/FileNotFoundException with message 'The file "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/780/thumb/bitcoin_cash.png?1547034541" does n ot exist'`

I used tinker framework to test this method before using in my project.
So my main question is why putFile doesn't stream the file whereas putFileAs does.
and my second question is how can I download and save an image file with specific file name without need to find the file extension in Laravel?

```
Storage::putFile('photos', "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/780/thumb/bitcoin_cash.png?1547034541") // FileNotFoundException

Storage::putFileAs('photos', "https://assets.coingecko.com/coins/images/780/thumb/bitcoin_cash.png?1547034541",'test') // Finds the file but I don't know how to add file extention
```